# How do I get useful error information from Unity with Sentry, running under WebGL?

Tags: unity-game-engine, sentry, unity-webgl

I've recently deployed a Unity application to the web using WebGL. I have Sentry integrated on the frontend logging exceptions, and I've added the Sentry SDK to Unity. The frontend seems to log no problem, however Unity seems to be struggling. Sometimes I'll get errors reported but a lot of the time I don't. To my knowledge there's no explicit onerror callback I can hook into. I've tried catching the exception in managed code and then reporting that to the frontend, but that doesn't seem to work either.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are you saying that sentry sdk for unity only doesn't work for webgl deployment or that it doesn't work at all?

Comment: I've not tested on other platforms, apart from through the editor, it seems to work through the editor but it's behaviour on WebGL seems odd.

Comment: I realize I am late to the game but have you checked [Wasm Sentry docs](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/native/guides/wasm/) and [Unity Sentry guide](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/unity/)?

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have done yeah, though this was a while ago now. It's my understanding that getting any useful error messages from WebGL and Unity basically requires a dev build, which is fairly untenable in production.